# Forbidden error in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have Apache/PHP setup on Windows 7. I am not able to visit /localhost/index.php or /localhost. I can open any other .php file from localhost or I can open index.php if it is in any subfolder of my documentroot.

Here are the relevant lines from httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/public_html"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes 
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```